# How to compare a string using a switch case in C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, switch-statement

I'm super new to C++.

I have to do a parser. Take a an input like "34+5-(9*8)" and insert it on a binary tree. My idea is compare every character in the string and determine if the character is a number or a simbol (+, -, *, /, etc) and insert it into a queue to use postfix notation and then insert it on the binary tree

What i want is ask the user to input the string, split the string into characters and then compare

something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <string>
using namespace std;

string cadena;
string numero;
int i;

int main(){

    cout<< "Type String";
    cin>> cadena;
    for (i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
        switch(cadena[i]{
            case "0":
            case "1":
            case "2":
            ...
            case "9":
                numero+=cadena[i];
        }
        cout << numero<<endl;
        numero="";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler complains i can't compare the current char (`cadena[i]`) with my string ("0").

Can somebody give me an idea of what to do?

I already have tried using char instead `std:string`, read other questions, etc.

Comment: `int isdigit( int ch );`

Comment: thanks to all the replies. The answer came from myselft from a project i already had.

The solution was convert the cadena[i] to int
   int car = (int) cadena[i]

and then compare with the ascii values.

Sorry, i'm really new to C++ and i also hate it haha

Answer (score 8):

The case labels in your switch statement right now are strings, but each individual piece of the string you're parsing is a char.  Try changing the double-quotes in the case labels to single-quotes.  For example:

```
switch (cadena[i]) {
    case '0':

    /* ... */
}
```

More generally, the constants in case labels must be integral numeric constants like int, char, short, etc.  You cannot put other types of values there.

That said, you might want to look at the `isdigit` function from The header `<cctype>`, which directly tests whether a character is a digit or not.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
    case "0":
    case "1":
```

use

```
    case '0':
    case '1':
```

(and for the others, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use strings (`const char*` values) as your case labels. Also, `numero+=cadena[i]` is not doing what you think it does: the value will be off significantly. You should use `numero = 10*numero + (cadena[i] - '0')` instead.

Moreover, the `switch` is entirely unnecessary: you can use `isdigit(cadena[i])` instead.

Finally, you do not even need a loop: there is a very convenient function that does what you need:

```
numero = atoi(cadena.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a `char` with a string literal (type `const char *`) without a custom function call of some kind.  You can, however, compare it to another `char`.  Replace "0", "1", etc. with `'0', '1', ...` and you should compile.